# Calculation Consistency Error in Pinescript V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to create a custom function which is counting the bars (by condition) and type them in a cell. I've thought I got the logic however can't solve this problem:

> *The function 'ta.crossover' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from the ternary operator or from the scope*

here is the function that I'm trying to create:

```
f_barssince(x, y) =>
    (x > y) ? ta.barssince(ta.crossover(x,y)) : (x < y) ? ta.barssince(ta.crossover(y,x)) : na
```

and the section which is typing the result in the cell.

```
symbol1_s2   = request.security(symbol1, symbol_timeframe, s2)
symbol1_avg0 = request.security(symbol1, symbol_timeframe, avg0)
symbol1_timing = f_barssince(symbol1_avg0,symbol1_s2)

table.cell(screener, 2, 1, text = str.tostring(symbol1_timing), text_color = color.white)
```

I've tried different configurations such as:

```
f_barssince(x, y) =>
    var crossover_result = (x > y) ? ta.crossover(x, y) : (x < y) ? ta.crossover(y, x) : na
    ta.barssince(crossover_result)
```

```
f_barssince(x, y) =>
    var crossover_result = (x > y) ? ta.crossover(x, y) : (x < y) ? ta.crossover(y, x) : na
    ta.barssince(crossover_result)
```

```
f_barssince(x,y) =>
    if x > y
        ta.barssince(ta.crossover(x,y))
    else 
        ta.barssince(ta.crossover(y,x))
```

none of them worked succesffuly.

Comment: solved it by a primitive method by still want to know the true way.

`if symbol1_avg0 > symbol1_s2
    table.cell(screener, 2, 1, text = str.tostring(symbol1_timing_a), text_color = color.white)
else
    table.cell(screener, 2, 1, text = str.tostring(symbol1_timing_b), text_color = color.white)`